# Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i'm facing a issue while testing the DAL Library which uses LINQ to SQL

Method that is being Tested as below (a simple one):

```
public List<tblAccount> GetAccountsByCustomer(tblCustomer customer)
{
    using (OnlineBankingDataClassesDataContext dbcntx = new OnlineBankingDataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var accounts = dbcntx.tblAccounts.Where(p => p.tblCustomer.ID.CompareTo(customer.ID)==0);
        return accounts.ToList<tblAccount>();
    }
}
```

Test code is as below:

```
static tblCustomer GetTopOneCustomer()
{
    OnlineBankingDataClassesDataContext dbcntx = new OnlineBankingDataClassesDataContext();
    var customers = dbcntx.tblCustomers.Take(1);
    return customers.Single<tblCustomer>();
}

public static void Should_List_All_Account_By_Customer()
{

    tblCustomer customer = GetTopOneCustomer();

    DataController dc = new DataController();
    List<tblAccount> accounts=dc.GetAccountsByCustomer(customer);
    foreach (tblAccount account in accounts)
    {
        string accountdetails=string.Format("Account ID:{0} \n Account Type:{1} \n Balance:{2} \n BranchName:{3} \n AccountNumber:{4}",
                        account.ID.ToString(), account.tblAccountType.Name, 
                        account.Balance.ToString(),
                        account.tblBranch.Name, account.Number);

        Console.WriteLine(accountdetails);

    }
}
```

I'm getting an error "Cannot access a disposed object." when accessing associated object like in this case, I'm using `account.tblAccountType.Name`. I know it has something to do with `DataContext`. How shall I get this code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbcntx` is a disposable object. The Garbage Collector can come along at any time after `GetTopOneCustomer()` has been called and dispose of it. Which is what looks like is happening.

Try changing `GetTopOneCustomer()` to:

```
static tblCustomer GetTopOneCustomer(OnlineBankingDataClassesDataContext dataContext) 
{
    //Stuff
}
```

Then inside `Should_List_All_Account_By_Customer()` change it like so:

```
using (OnlineBankingDataClassesDataContext dataContext = new OnlineBankingDataClassesDataContext())
{
    tblCustomer customer = GetTopOneCustomer(dataContext); 
    //More Stuff
}
```

This way you control the lifetime of the `dataContext`.

Comment: I normally wrap them in a class, so as the class is active your database connection will be active.

Comment: @DaveShaw The problem is that related objects are being accessed in entities after the dbcntx DataContext has been disposed. The GetTopOneCustomer shouldn't cause any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the the DataContext is in a using statement, `using (OnlineBankingDataClassesDataContext dbcntx = new OnlineBankingDataClassesDataContext())`
 Disposed will be called on it as soon as the context goes out of scope. This results in all entities beeing detached and all actions on the entity that requires a DataContext will fail. 
This is what happens when `account.Balance.ToString()` is called.

One way to solve this is by creating a new context and use `context.Attach(entity)`.

Comment: where is the using statement the `DataContext` is in?

Comment: Ah, did not scroll up enough.