# Error when doing two calls from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting the error "Cannot acess to disposable object" when I try to use the same connection. So this is my Oracle context:

```
public class MyOracleContext
{
    DbConnection connection;

    public MyOracleContext()
    {

        connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public TOut ExecuteCommand<TOut>(IDbCommand command, Func<IDataReader, TOut> mapHelper)
    {
        TOut result = default(TOut);
        try
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                using (command)
                {
                    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                    }
                    using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                    {
                        result = mapHelper(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception _exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error!" + _exp.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public IDbCommand GetCommand()
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = (OracleCommand)connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        return cmd;
    }

    public IDataParameter GetParameter()
    {
        return new OracleParameter();
    }

    public bool ExecuteCommand(IDbCommand command)
    {
        bool result;
        try
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                command.Prepare();
                using (command)
                {
                    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                    }
                    result = command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception _exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error!" + _exp.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public DbParameter GetParameter(string name, object value)
    {
        OracleParameter para = new OracleParameter(name, value);
        para.Size = int.MaxValue;
        return para;
    }
}
```

I use the **ExecuteCommand** to Get results from DB, and the ExecuteCommand to, for eg, Insert. But, when I use the two commands on the same method, it gives me the error **"Cannot access to disposable object"**, when I do Connection.Open, on the method **ExecuteCommand** . But if i do the inverse order (use first the ExecuteCommand and then use ExecuteCommand), it pass. The problem is that I want to get results from the BD, to compare and then insert. Any idea why? I've been stuck here for hours

Comment: why not create new connection?

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365338/cannot-access-a-disposed-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are holding the `DbConnection` as a property of the class, but then disposing of it after executing a command.  If another command is then executed using the same instance, then it's trying to use a disposed connection.

Connections are pooled by .NET, so they're relatively cheap to create.  I would just create the command in the `ExceuteCommand` method:

```
public TOut ExecuteCommand<TOut>(IDbCommand command, Func<IDataReader, TOut> mapHelper)
{
    TOut result = default(TOut);
    //try
    //{
        using (DbConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            //using (command)
            //{
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                {
                    result = mapHelper(reader);
                }
            //}
        }
    }
    //catch (Exception _exp)
    //{
    //    throw new Exception("Error!" + _exp.Message);
    //}
    return result;
}
```

There are two other changes I would suggest:

- You should not be disposing the *command* in this method since it didn't create it.  Whatever is responsible for creating a disposable item is 
  responsible for disposing of it.
- Do not catch any exception simply to throw another plain vanilla `Exception` with just the error message extracted.  Either just let the exception bubble up or do something meaningful (log it, add some more context, etc) and then either throw a new exception *attaching the original exception* as the `InnerException` or rethrow the exception

Comment: Stanley, thanks for the detailed explanation. Followed your instructions, but now I'm getting the error "Connection must be open" on **using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))** . Why? I'm opening the conection before!

Comment: You need to associate the command with the connection you created : `command.Connection = connection`.  These types of things are usually why commands and connections are not abstracted like this  - there is enough coupling that it's usually cleaner to manage them together, even if it means some code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "return result;" to inside the using(){ }

Like that:

```
public TOut ExecuteCommand<TOut>(IDbCommand command, Func<IDataReader, TOut> mapHelper)
{
    TOut result = default(TOut);
    try
    {
        using (connection)
        {
            using (command)
            {
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                {
                   return result = mapHelper(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception _exp)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error!" + _exp.Message);
    }

}
```